# VSC Python: required and optional args in launch.json

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I'm working in Visual Studio Code with Python on a project that is called with `main(args)`. There are optional and required arguments. The code looks like this:

```py
import sys
import argparse

def main(args):
    print(args.mode)
    print(args.path)
    return 0

if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("--mode", type=str, choices=["opt1","opt2"], default="opt1")
    parser.add_argument("path", type=str)
    args = parser.parse_args()
    sys.exit(main(args))
```

Now I want to debug the code in VSC and use a `launch.json` file for this process to speed it up. How do I setup my launch.json file correctly for both arguments?

Currently my `launch.json` looks like this:

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "something",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "%{file}",
            "args": [
                "--mode","opt2",
                "path","~/some_path",
            ],
            "console": "integratedTerminal"
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm getting an error every time I start the debug process:
`error: the following arguments are required: path`
Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: `"path"` is not an option  use `"--path"`

Comment: You should accept the answer by clicking on tick icon ✅ which is at left of the answer, so that community can understand that the question has been answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I now found a solution. So I have made 2 mistakes here:

1. The `args` statement in `launch.json` is wrong
2. The `args` specified are not passed to the debugger

#### To 1

Since I need an optional argument e.g. `--mode` AND a required argument e.g. `path` the correct syntax in the `launch.json` is:

```json
"args": ["--mode=opt2", "~/path_to_some_folder"],
```

#### To 2

In order to ensure that the launch options specified in `launch.json` are being used by the debugger simply add `"purpose": ["debug-in-terminal"]` to it.

Comment: your "to 2" is only for if you want to debug a file in a terminal. not when using "regular" launch configs